# Looping through a function with two arguments

Tags: python

I have a function with two arguments. Argument a is mandatory, argument b is optional.

I'd like to call the function in a loop with the arguments stored in a list, tuple or dictionary, instead of having to write:

```
function(argument1a)
function(argument2a,argument2b)
function(argument3a,argument3b)
function(argument4a)
function(argument5a)
function(argument6a,argument6b)
```

I'd like do something like:

```
args = [argument1a, argument2a, argument2b, argument3a, argument3b, argument4a, argument5a, argument6a, argument6b]

for arg in arguments:
    function(a,b)
```

Which type of storage array should I choose and what would the loop look like?

Comment: Im still very confused at what you are trying to achieve. What is the point of this function?

Comment: can we see the code for your `function`?

Comment: welcome to SO!  it's not clear what you're trying to do here unfortunately, OP.  assuming there's not something distinguishable about `argb` (that you could catch with logic), then it will not be distinguishable from `arga` at present, since it's just another item in a list.  what is the end goal?  can you describe what you want to get out of your loop -- i.e., the end product?

Comment: *Lists* in Python are objects. Everything in Python is an object.  Lists can store other Lists.  So you would want to store a List of 2 items each like @alex's answer.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed so clear in my head. I clearly have a long way to go. Basically the argument a is an URL, the argument b is a name. The function parses the name out of the URL when no argument b is given. Does that make more sense? I'll try to pastebin the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want something like

```
>>> def function(a, b=0): print a, b
... 
>>> args = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1]]
>>> for arg in args: function(*arg)
... 
1 1
1 2
1 0
```

Comment: It seems that OP does not have list of lists.

Comment: If I understand correctly he was asking what data structure to use in order to be able to loop through the arguments as mentioned. He suggested very different ones as acceptable (tuples and dictionaries, for instance). Let's see what he has to say.

Comment: I know that you show your example in python shell but I think will be better to use more pythonic syntax. The code is correct but not follow the PEP8